# How to update a deployed web packaged?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-deployment

I like to deploy a web application with Web Deyploment. I'll need to hand the package to an admin which will installed it. The admin install the package via UI of the IIS Manager. On installation there a lot of parameters which need to fill in. These is working fine so far.

But now I need to update the deployed package. How to do this without the need to fill out the parameters again? All ways I found so far need enter the parameters again. So I must have overseen something.

Thanks.

Comment: this is not a direct answer for your question, but more like a suggestion, try to use VS2010 WebDeploy and get rid of the hassle.
if this is not possible, I will look for a solution for you.

Comment: What kind of parameter you want to enter. Can you explain?

Comment: as  Mohammed ElSayed suggested you can download webdeploy package from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19995

Comment: I'm not positive but I think the OP is saying they he is creating a deployment packing using visual studio's package option.  Instead of using the generated cmd file (and msdeploy) his admin is using the IIS gui to import the zip (which comes with Web Deploy 2.0) ?

Comment: Yeah ... Kenneth is right.I'm already using VS2012 to build the package. Since I need to hand the zip file to an admin I can't use the publish option.

Comment: @skhurams: beside of the the normal db parameters there are about 15 parameters which are different on each installation (like proxy settings, UNC network paths, internal filter values and so on...)